# How can I import crt and key through of the Jrockit Keytool

Tags: ssl, weblogic, keytool, crt, jrockit

I need to import a new SSL certificate on my server (development environment) and every time I have done it I had used this command below:

```
/oracle/binaries/jrockit/bin/keytool -import -alias mycerts -keystore /oracle/binaries/jrockit/jre/lib/security/cacerts -trustcacerts -file /home/otusr/gustavo/mycerts.crt
```

But as you can see, I use a single file that is .crt...

However, I have received from another area two files,a .crt and a .key, but I couldn't find or understand how I can import them.

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You received it why? Nobody should be giving uou a private key. Otherwise it isn't private.

Comment: I don't Know... I believe that the key is necessary for importantion.

Comment: Note that this is not a JRockit JVM specific question, keytool is a regular JDK tool.